# Programmatically create table to avoid much data in one table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Limited to Mssql, consider to design a system for long-term use about 10 years. And users insert 10K data in one table every day, so to avoid table heavy, the system creates table programmatically according to what the data belong to.
Hence the database is full of tables like that

- table_AAA
- table_BBB
- table_CCC
- table_DDD ...

User will create the schema they want but limited to the six type they can choose.

table_AAA schema:

1. type1 aa
2. type3 bb
3. type1 cc
4. type2 dd ...

So each schema of table will be different.

But it's really really annoying to get data with orm or do anything we want.
Is there a good idea to design system like this?

This system is similar to a online questionnaire that can be designed by user.

Comment: Use table partitioning.

Comment: Yes you can create a partition function based on years maybe. Actually you can seperate hot data which is queried frequently to a data file or may be into a few data files and keep all other into slower disk data files. Or keep hot data in memory and others on disks